# $ \| v\| \leq Ce^x\| w\| \quad \left(x\rightarrow 0 \right) $ if $\| w\|=0$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Let $v\in \mathbb{R}^J$ and $J\in \mathbb{N}$.

I have the follow inequality:
$$
\| v\| \leq 
\| w\| + x \quad \left(x\rightarrow 0 \right)
$$
If $\|w\|\not=0$ we can find a $C$ positive constant with $C\|w\|>1$ and we have
$$
\| v\| \leq 
 Ce^x\| w\| \quad \left(x\rightarrow 0 \right)
$$

If $\|w\|=0$ we have 
$$
\|v\|\leq x \quad \left(x\rightarrow 0\right)
$$ 
My question is: We can conclude $\|v\| =0$?

Comment: Please use \| for norm, it formats much better.

Comment: Thank you, for next time I know :)

Comment: If $\|w\|=0$ then the numerator is zero for all $x$ and the denominator isn't zero for any $x\not=0$, so in that case the limit is zero, not one.

Comment: In fact if $\|w\|=0$ then $\|v\|\leq0$, so $v$ would also have to be $(0,\dots,0)$.

Comment: Thank you, but I'm not sure $\|w\|=0$ implies $\|v\|$ = 0

Comment: You're trying to show $\|v\|\leq Ce^x\|w\|$.  But if $w=(0,\dots,0)$ then the only way this is true is if $v=(0,\dots,0)$ too, because the RHS is zero.

Comment: of course I agree with you but I don't how to prove it

Comment: Since $C\|w\|>1$, it is impossible that $w=(0,\dots,0)$ anyway, so why are you trying to handle that case?

Comment: ok, so $\|w\|=0 \rightarrow \|v\|=0$ is a condition

Comment: I'm sorry I'm getting a bit confused with exactly what you are given and what you are trying to prove.  Can you restate the question?

Comment: ok, I edit my question

Comment: I changed the question

Comment: Yes, you just need the following basic fact. Let $a\in\mathbb R$ with $a\geq0$.  Suppose $a<\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon>0$.  Then $a=0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answers :)

Comment: No problem!  :-)